# Python class instance most recent overwriting all others

Tags: python, file, class, dictionary, object

I've got an assignment where I have to create a class for Employees, read in a text file containing employee information to store as an object, read in an hours worked file and the create a payment information dictionary out of the files. So, far it seems to be working fine as long as their is only one employee in the employee text file but as soon as I include a second, the first is overwritten and the information for the second is what's created. This is some of the information I have so far:

```
class Staff:
    staffData = {}

    def __init__(self, EmpID, LName, FName, RHours, HRate, OTMult, TaxC, SBand, Date, HrsWorked):
        self.EmpID = EmpID
        self.LName = LName
        self.FName = FName
        self.RHours = RHours
        self.HRate = HRate
        self.OTMult = OTMult
        self.TaxC = TaxC
        self.SBand = SBand
        self.Date = Date
        self.HrsWorked = HrsWorked
        Staff.staffData[EmpID] = self

    def setup(staff ,hrs):  # staff and hrs are text files
        with open(staff) as empFile:
            for line in empFile:
                SID, LN, FN, RH, HR, OTM, TC, SB = line.split()
            with open(hrs) as hFile:
                for line in hFile:
                    SID, date, HrsWorked = line.split()
                    stf = Staff(SID, LN, FN, int(RH), int(HR), float(OTM), int(TC), int(SB),date, HrsWorked)
                    return stf

    def paySlip(self,HrsWorked, date):
        paymentDict = {}

        #creates paySlip using information from instance and creates others by performing 
         calculations
        return paymentDict

jg = Staff.setup('Staff.txt', 'Hrs.txt')
dic = jg.paySlip(42,'31/10/2021')
print(dic)
```

This is what I have so far, and it returns the correct output, but when I include a second line with a second staff member that is where I get the issues. Also, just a note, the parameters for paySlip have got to be date and hours worked from the hours text file and not just the text file. I'm quite new to programming so apologies if this is a basic fix, I've spent the last 3 days trying to figure it out by visiting different boards and websites. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Staff.staffData[EmpID] = self` will overwrite the class variable. You want `self.staffData[EmpID]`. It also probably isn't sensible to instantiate the class with `setup`, then have `setup` return instances of the class.

Comment: `staffData` would appear to be a collection of instances of `Staff`. The problem is that `setup` returns prematurely and does not use every line of `empFile`, only the last line.

Comment: Thanks for the input @match, when I made the change you recommended it returned this error. I'm guessing the '12345' it refers to is the EmpID of the first employee: Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 69, in <module>
    jg = Staff.setup('Staff.txt', 'Hrs.txt')
, line 24, in setup
    stf = Staff(SID, LN, FN, int(RH), int(HR), float(OTM), int(TC), int(SB),date, HrsWorked)
   line 15, in __init__
    self.staffData[EmpID]
KeyError: '12345'

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the feedback, I'm not 100% I 'm understanding. What can I do to rectify the issue?

Comment: @chepner I think I understand what you mean. The setup reads through the last line of the EmpFile and returns whatever information is there, but I don't understand why my code is doing that. Do I need to find a way to split the lines in Emp file first and store them separately, then split these lines to input the information into the class instances?

Comment: You read the entire `hrs` file without remembering what was on a line; you only save the *last* line. Then with the `staffs` file, you return after reading the first line. You need to save more information in memory as you read each file. There seems to be an assumption that line `i` of one file corresponds to line `i` of the other; you might want something like `for staff_data, hr_data in zip(empFile, hFile): ...`

Comment: Or, you'll need to read all of `hrs` into a `dict`, keyed with `SID`, then lookup the appropriate data using the `SID` in the `staffs` file to create the appropriate instance of `Staff`.

Comment: `setup`, by the way, should be a static method, or (better yet) defined as a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
return stf
```

return from the setup funktion after readin the first line no matter what. If you want to store all line in a list of Staff objects you need to build that list and then return it. something like that

```
        with open(hrs) as hFile:
            stf = []
            for line in hFile:
                SID, date, HrsWorked = line.split()
                stf.append(Staff(SID, LN, FN, int(RH), int(HR), float(OTM), int(TC), int(SB),date, HrsWorked))
            return stf
```

then you should get all lines in hFile. That said the way this is build is just stange. you build a staff object to breat a list of staff objects ?

you might wanna restructure your code into a Staff class and StaffMember class?   this way you have a Staff object that has Members with hours. But i can be wrong here since i dont see the full picture

cheers

Markus

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I did as you mentioned and created an empty stf list before reading the files and appending to the stf list. But I got the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'paySlip'. Also, the assignment requested only one class created

Comment: you now have a list of staff objects so you neet to itterate over the list and call paySlip on each of em.